# Is Google Associate Android Developer Certification Enough For Work Visa To Prove The Qualification

Tags: software-industry, job-search, germany, visa

My question is specifically for Germany, but in case you know the procedures of other EU countries or Canada and you can answer to this question for those countries you're welcome to share your knowledge.

To get a work visa in Germany, there is a requirement that asks for proof of qualification. Can one meet this requirement with Associate Android Developer Certification by Google for Android developer jobs?

Comment: Proof of which qualification?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Proof for your qualification for the job you are applying. In this case software developing for Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply to have your qualifications recognised in Germany contact  the Bundesagentur für Arbeit (BA, the Federal Employment Agency).

https://www.arbeitsagentur.de/en/recognition-of-qualifications

---

Vocational training and certificates in either IT or other fields are **not sufficient** to qualify for a work and residency permit under the **EU Bluecard skilled workers program**.

That requires the equivalent of a German higher education degree.

http://www.bamf.de/EN/Infothek/FragenAntworten/BlaueKarteEU/blaue-karte-eu-node.html

---

If instead you are pursuing a **normal residency permit with associated work permit** you need to  have **a confirmed job offer**. As far as I know the job offer will be the most important part of that application for getting consent from the Bundesagentur für Arbeit (BA, the Federal Employment Agency).

As far as I’m aware software development is not a profession that is protected with specific entry requirements with regards to training and certification (unlike for instance what a medical doctor would need to have to practice medicine).
Vocational training and certificates relevant to that job offer, as well as work experience will certainly support your application, but may not even be required at all.

https://www.arbeitsagentur.de/en/german-labour-market

Answer (score 0):

A certificate of training from a course run by the official developers usually carries significant weight where employability is concerned.

This *should* be enough to count as proof of your competency, but if you have any extra Java related certificates (does not have to be Android), that can also help your case.

Comment: emphasis on SHOULD. ask the official authorities, we are not an official source